# excel vba userform set quantity value cannot less then 0

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a user form that is use to input an item to my inventory. What I want is that the quantity that user input can't be less than 0 so that my staff cannot deduct my inventory item.

I wrote code like this for it but when I input -1 the quantity value is still deducted.

```
If tbQty.Value > 0 Then
    lastRow2 = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A" & lastRow2).Value = CDate(tbDate)
    .Range("B" & lastRow2).Value = str
    .Range("C" & lastRow2).Value = tbColor.Value
    .Range("D" & lastRow2).Value = Val(tbQty.Value)
    .Range("E" & lastRow2).Value = Val(tbPrice.Value)
    .Range("G" & lastRow2).Value = UCase(tbProduct.Value)
End If
```

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904474/restricting-user-input-to-integers-on-a-userform-textbox) may be of use

Comment: `tbQty.Value` will be a `String`, you want to first validate that it's a numeric value, then store the converted numeric value into a local variable, and compare *that variable* against 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a `VBA UserForm` to the data input. If the user writes the number on a text box (let's say `TextBox1`), you could prevent the input of a negative number (or anything but a non negative number) with the `Event Caller`:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    Select Case KeyAscii
        Case 46, 48 To 57
        Case Else
        KeyAscii = 0
    End Select
End Sub
```

This code permits an input of a decimal non negative number (with a `.`as the decimal separator). If in your country (like on my own) you use commas for this, change `Case 46, 48 To 57` with `Case 44, 48 To 57`.

After this you just have to worry about getting the value of the input.

Comment: it works !, but how if i dont want it to be decimal also ?

Comment: Just place `Case 48 To 57` instead.